# LeetCode Counting Bits in Swift

Tags: programming-challenge, swift

I solve this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/counting-bits/) in Swift. I am looking for a code review, thanks!

> Given a non negative integer number num. For every numbers i in the
>   range 0 ≤ i ≤ num calculate the number of 1's in their binary
>   representation and return them as an array.

```
class Solution {
    func countBits(num: Int) -> [Int] {
        var nums = [Int](count: num+1, repeatedValue: 0)
        if num == 0 { // if num is 0
            return nums
        }
        for i in 1...num {
            nums[i] = binaryOnes(i)
        }
        return nums
    }
    func binaryOnes(num: Int) -> Int {
        var num = num
        var count = 0
        repeat  {
            if num % 2 == 0 { // even numbers
                num /= 2
            } else { // all odd numbers
                num = (num-1)/2
                count += 1
            }
        } while num > 1
        if num == 1 { // when num is 1 at the end
            count += 1
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

Comment: Just putting the Swift built-in solution should anyone be looking for it here.(0...n).map{$0.nonzeroBitCount}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods don't use any state of the `Solution` class, so they should
be `static` methods of that type, or global functions.

`binaryOnes()` can be simplified. If you replace

```
repeat { ... } while num > 1
```

by

```
while num > 0 { ... }
```

then the additional check for `num == 1` becomes obsolete:

```
func binaryOnes(num: Int) -> Int {
    var num = num
    var count = 0
    while num > 0 {
        if num % 2 == 0 { // even numbers
            num /= 2
        } else { // all odd numbers
            num = (num-1)/2
            count += 1
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

Now observe that `num % 2` gives the least significant bit of 
the number (`0` or `1`), and `num /= 2` is a *truncating* division.
Therefore the function can be simplified to

```
func binaryOnes(num: Int) -> Int {
    var num = num
    var count = 0
    while num > 0 {
        count += num % 2
        num /= 2
    }
    return count
}
```

More sophisticated bit counting methods can be found at
https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html, they can
be more effective for large numbers.

In `countBits`, the check for `num == 0` is not necessary,
because `1...num` is the empty range in that case:

```
func countBits(num: Int) -> [Int] {
    var nums = [Int](count: num+1, repeatedValue: 0)
    for i in 1...num {
        nums[i] = binaryOnes(i)
    }
    return nums
}
```

Calling the variables `num` and `nums` could be confusing,
`upTo:` might be a better name for the parameter.

But what the function actually does is to *map* the numbers
`0...upTo` to their bit count. That can be done directly with
a `map()` method:

```
func countBits(upTo: Int) -> [Int] {
    return (0...upTo).map(binaryOnes)
}
```

An alternative approach would be to use the fact that

```
bitCount(n) = bitCount(n/2) + (n % 2)
```

for all (positive) integers `n`. Together with `bitCount(0) = 0`
this is a recursive computation method. But since you store the
bit counts in an array anyway, this can be implemented as
a simple iteration:

```
func countBits1(upTo: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result = [ 0 ]
    for i in 1...upTo {
        result.append(result[i/2] + (i % 2))
    }
    return result
}
```

Now the `binaryOnes()` function is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

//  *********   338. Counting Bits  *********

The previous solution will fail for the input [0].

```
func countBits(_ num: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result = [0]
    guard num != 0 else {
        return result
    }
    for i in 1...num {
        result.append(result[i/2] + (i % 2))
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the constructive criticism. Yup I wrote it like stack-overflow and not like code-review. Will take your suggestion for my future responses.